# Can a head teacher forbid the use of face masks in school?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19

Basically the opposite of [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158640/can-a-uk-employer-force-you-to-wear-a-face-mask).

I know someone who works in an English secondary school (ages 11 - 18), and they've said that their headteacher has forbidden staff from wearing face masks because they'll "cause distress."

But surely this can't be demanded of them, and is more of a request (which can be ignored)?

Despite this, the vast majority of staff (and students) have chosen not to wear masks, even though they may want to - they don't wear them because "nobody else does." Maybe they're afraid of losing their jobs, although surely they couldn't be fired for adhering to government advice.

This head teacher seems to be burying their head in the sand and acting like everything is normal, which I find somewhat bizarre. From what I've heard about conditions in the school, its response to the pandemic has been fairly shambolic, and staff don't have much confidence or feel safe.

Comment: Call the police, contact local MP and Education Minister, stand back and wait for results.

Comment: @Jack please see my amendments - it's more that the staff are being discouraged from wearing masks. The students are aged 11+.

Comment: sounds like someone trying to drum up a bit of drama, best to ignore it.

Comment: Which part of the UK?  AIUI, England, Scotland, Wales, and Northern Ireland all have different government guidelines on CoViD-19 safety in schools.  And is OP's acquaintance in a trade union?  The main unions representing teachers (and other school staff) in the UK definitely have a position on this issue.

Comment: @Jack You know what actually causes health issues? COVID-19.

Comment: @Studoku You should mark irony as such, it does not transport well online.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs What irony?

Comment: @Studoku You say the UK government tries to get the numbers up? I am not aware of any governments, including some pretty unsavoury ones, that are interested in high infection rates (except for the controversial idea of herd immunity which, however, by now seems off the table). So I inferred that you must be ironic.

Comment: @Jack citation needed.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Well there's not reason they'd want to cure COVID, and there's no evidence they are...

Comment: @Studoku I think there are a lot of reasons to get the pandemic under control; international travel, tourism, business, being able to open shops etc. As for your second sentence, incompetence should not be mistaken for malice. They simply have no idea how to handle it, because the government went into office with a 1-issue agenda and simply ignored that most of the time it's the events that dictate the issues and they need to be able to handle whatever emergency would come up. They were mentally simply completely unprepared to anything outside their agenda.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, it seems that you are a reasonable, clear thinking, and intelligent person. I can tell you that what goes on in the minds of some people in the UK is beyond your imagination.

Comment: @gnasher729 If indeed true, that'd be a very depressing outlook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OP has now clarified that the school in question is in England, in which case the official government guidance on face coverings in schools is [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/face-coverings-in-education/face-coverings-in-education).  It recommends against face coverings in classrooms, and leaves the decision up to individual headteachers in other parts of the school.  The main unions representing [teachers](https://neu.org.uk/media/12081/view) and [ancillary staff in schools](https://www.unison.org.uk/news/2020/08/school-staff-must-allowed-wear-masks-safe-reopening-says-unison/) are not at all happy about this position.

Comment: And there was me thinking the original question before any edit was tagged “United Kingdom”. At least that was ehat led me to my, and the first, comment.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, it was so tagged, but different parts of the UK have different policies, so it needed narrowing down to England before answering.  OP narrowed it down with a text edit 5 hours ago.